# loop to next update after row_count >0 in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have the following procedure in mysql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE accidents.`task_6_proce`()
BEGIN

  DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE v_pkid INTEGER;
  DECLARE v_mine INTEGER;
  DECLARE v_date DATETIME;
  DECLARE v_lat INTEGER;
  DECLARE v_lng INTEGER;
  DECLARE v_next_date DATE;
  DECLARE i INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE weather_cursor CURSOR FOR select pkid, mine_id, accident_dt, lat, lng
                              from test_unfilteredfull
                              where pkid between 1 and 100;

-- declare NOT FOUND handler
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
    FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;
OPEN weather_cursor;

get_update: LOOP

    FETCH weather_cursor INTO v_pkid, v_mine, v_date, v_lat, v_lng;

    SET v_next_date = DATE_ADD(v_date,INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    -- select v_date, v_next_date;

    IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
        LEAVE get_update;
    END IF;
last_update: loop  
      UPDATE mytable mt INNER JOIN myvalues mv
         ON mv.date = v_next_date and
         mt.pkid = v_pkid 
      SET mt.tmax = mv.tmax, mt.tmin = mv.tmin, mt.dayl= mv.dayl ,
          mt.prcp = mv.prcp , mt.srad = mv.srad, mt.swe=mv.swe, mt.vp=mv.vp
    WHERE mv.Longitude_MAX >= v_lng and 
      mv.Longitude_MIN <= v_lng and 
      mv.Latitude_MAX >=  v_lat and  
      mv.Latitude_MIN <= v_lat;
if ROW_COUNT() > 0 then
   LEAVE last_update;
end if;

IF v_next_date = LAST_DAY(v_next_date) then
   LEAVE last_update;
end if;

  SET v_next_date = DATE_ADD(v_next_date,INTERVAL 1 DAY);
  SET i = i+1;
end LOOP last_update;
END LOOP get_update;

CLOSE weather_cursor;
commit;  

END;
```

here the problem with 
`if ROW_COUNT() > 0 then
       LEAVE last_update;
    end if;`
when the first record is updated it leave the loop and end the procedure. how to accomplish that the end but only for that record and begin for the next pkid in the cursor?

Comment: When, however, you are updating until the last day of a date, checking for `row_count()` is not useful, anyway. Comment out that block and see the difference.

Comment: let me check, and the last day I am using to for the last day of the month, is this correct?

Comment: Yes. Keep that condition included and comment out `row_count()` code block.